# In a CrossValidator with a pipeline estimator. How data goes through the pipeline?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Taking a look at [ML Tuning: Cross-Validation](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/ml-tuning.html#cross-validation) I have some doubts about how the data goes through a Spark pipeline.

Let's imagine that I want to process a dataset similar to the following one:

```
| sqfeet | #rooms | neighbourhood | price |
|--------|--------|---------------|-------|
| 50     | 2      | GR4242        | 100   |
| 120    | 3      | GR4242        | 220   |
| 100    | 2      | FD0202        | 180   |
```

What I've been doing in other ML frameworks was:

1. Preprocess **ALL** the data. For example, one shot encoding the column `neighbourhood`.
2. Split data in train/test.
3. Perform hyperparameter tuning using CV on train set.
4. Get an unbiased metric of the performance of the model using the test set.

However, using the code I've linked above the method `transform` of my custom Transformer is called 2 * number of folds of CV * cross product of parameter grid.

Test program:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.Identifiable
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, Transformer}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}


// Don't worry, the parallelism is set to 1
object Counter {
  var timesCalled = 0
}

class CustomTransformer(override val uid: String = Identifiable.randomUID("custom"))
  extends Transformer {

  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    println(s"Times called ${Counter.timesCalled}. Dataset passed:")
    dataset.show()
    Counter.timesCalled += 1
    dataset.toDF()
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Transformer = defaultCopy(extra)

  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = schema
}

object TestApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    lazy val spark: SparkSession =
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("testApp")
        .master("local[1]")
        .getOrCreate()

    // Prepare training data from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
    val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (50f, 2, "GR4242", 100f),
      (120f, 3, "GR4242", 220f),
      (100f, 2, "FD0202", 180f)
    )).toDF("sqfeet", "#rooms", "neighbourhood", "label")

    //    val stringIndexer = new StringIndexer()
    //      .setInputCol("neighbourhood")
    //      .setOutputCol("neighbourhood_index")
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(Array("sqfeet", "#rooms"))
      .setOutputCol("features")
    val customTransformer = new CustomTransformer()
    val lr = new LogisticRegression()
      .setMaxIter(10)
    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(assembler, customTransformer, lr))

    val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
      .addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
      .build()

    val cv = new CrossValidator()
      .setEstimator(pipeline)
      .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator)
      .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
      .setNumFolds(2)

    val cvModel = cv.fit(training)

  }

}
```

The output is:

```
Times called 0. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
| 100.0|     2|       FD0202|180.0|[100.0,2.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 1. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|  50.0|     2|       GR4242|100.0| [50.0,2.0]|
| 120.0|     3|       GR4242|220.0|[120.0,3.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 2. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
| 100.0|     2|       FD0202|180.0|[100.0,2.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 3. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|  50.0|     2|       GR4242|100.0| [50.0,2.0]|
| 120.0|     3|       GR4242|220.0|[120.0,3.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 4. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|  50.0|     2|       GR4242|100.0| [50.0,2.0]|
| 120.0|     3|       GR4242|220.0|[120.0,3.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 5. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
| 100.0|     2|       FD0202|180.0|[100.0,2.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 6. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|  50.0|     2|       GR4242|100.0| [50.0,2.0]|
| 120.0|     3|       GR4242|220.0|[120.0,3.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 7. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
| 100.0|     2|       FD0202|180.0|[100.0,2.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+

Times called 8. Dataset passed:
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|sqfeet|#rooms|neighbourhood|label|   features|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
|  50.0|     2|       GR4242|100.0| [50.0,2.0]|
| 120.0|     3|       GR4242|220.0|[120.0,3.0]|
| 100.0|     2|       FD0202|180.0|[100.0,2.0]|
+------+------+-------------+-----+-----------+
```

I suppose odd numbers represent the training phase and even numbers represent the test phase.

Would not be more efficient to do all those expensive preprocessing calculations that are done in the transformers just once?

Comment: Have you tried `cache` at the end of `transform` method?

Comment: Yes. The thing is that the dataset passed to the `transform` method is always different because it comes from a different fold. The solution that I have found is to separate the pipeline in two. Executing the first one for the heavy preprocessing and setting the main pipeline as the estimator for the `CrossValidator`, as you can see in this question: [Optimal way to create a ml pipeline in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911694/optimal-way-to-create-a-ml-pipeline-in-apache-spark-for-dataset-with-high-number?rq=1)